# BufferedReader.readLine() cuts off beginning of the line

Tags: java, readline, bufferedreader

I have a problem with reading a file.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(
                         new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
   parseLine(line);
}

Trouble causing line:
 a:38:{s:10:"aaaaaaaaaa";s:6:"215302";s:4:"bbbb";s:9:"新村莊";s:10:"cccccccccc";s:6:"330345";s:6:"dddddd";s:3:"-68";s:6:"eeeeee";s:3:"-12";s:9:"fffffffff";s:4:"3470";s:7:"ggggggg";s:1:"3";s:10:"hhhhhhhhhh";s:1:"2";s:7:"iiiiiii";s:3:"391";s:11:"jjjjjjjjjjj";s:1:"2";s:15:"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj";s:1:"8";s:15:"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj";s:1:"8";s:15:"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj";s:1:"8";s:16:"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj";s:2:"12";s:14:"jjjjjjjjjjjjjj";N;s:11:"jjjjjjjjjjj";N;s:13:"jjjjjjjjjjjjj";N;s:20:"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj";s:1:"1"... etc
```

At about the 30th file in row about 105000, readline() cuts off the first 69 characters. The line has a total of 936 characters.

Any idea why `readline()` cuts off the characters? (BTW, there are lines that are longer!)

Comment: We need more information.  Give us a stripped-down file that reproduces the problem.  As a guess, the encoding you've specified might be wrong.

Comment: I suspect you've got diagnostic problems... e.g. the line contains some unprintable characters which are confusing your display code. `readLine()` itself does *not* cut off the beginning of the line.

Comment: Hi all, this is the line that causes trouble:

Comment: It really causes trouble, because I cannot see it :)

Comment: @Marcus paste the troubling line in the your question, preferably under code style... so that we can see if there is an issue with special char.

Comment: I use this parser. But the to feed the parser with each line I need something to read the file line by line.

Comment: I see some Chinese/Japanese (sorry if other) characters: 新. try removing them, and try to read again to see if that's the problem. (I know its UTF-8, but its worth to try :) )

Comment: The exaxt same expression occurs several times before and does not cause any problems.

Comment: Actually, I do not care about the characters in those this field. Is there a way to skip them, because it does not properly read in...

Comment: Marcus, can you try again, but do not use the BufferedReader? Just read directly from the InputStreamReader instead of wrapping it into a BufferedReader. Just for debugging puposes...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code but with a simple System.out.println(line) where you call the parseLine(line) method and everything works fine: your sample trouble causing line appears correct in my console.

Please try yourself and let us see your parseLine(line) method.